# Why doesn't my associations go both ways in ActiveRecord?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations

So I'm connecting to a legacy database.  I have two tables, `Sites` and `States`.

A `Site` has one `State` and a `State` can belong to many `Sites`

```
# Sites.rb
has_one :state, :primary_key => "StateKey", :foreign_key => "StateKey"

# States.rb
belongs_to :sites, :class_name => "Sites", :primary_key => "SiteKey", :foreign_key => "SiteKey"
```

As you can see I have to manually set the foreign keys and primary keys.

So this works:

```
Sites.first.state  # one record returned (the state)
```

This does not:

```
States.first.sites  # nil returned.  Doesn't even appear to hit AR
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the pair `has_many`, `belongs_to`:

```
# Sites.rb
belongs_to :state, :primary_key => "StateKey", :foreign_key => "StateKey"

# States.rb
has_many :sites, :class_name => "Sites", :primary_key => "StateKey", :foreign_key => "StateKey"
```

Take a look at [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

When you have a one-to-many association it is standard practice to use `belongs_to` and `has_many` in the two model classes. `has_one` is a special case of `has_many`. `belongs_to` says that the foreign key is in the model declaring the association, and `has_one`, `has_many` say the foreign key is in the other model.